# Why is (result >> 8) & hfm slower than ((op1 ^ result ^ op2) >> 8) & hfm in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I entered this simple code into LINQPad 7 to see which code was faster.  I was surprised to see that the second timing loop was consistently slower?  Can anyone explain why?

```cs
void Main()
{
  const byte hfm = 0b0001_0000;
  
  UInt16 operand1 = 0x2;
  UInt16 operand2 = 0xFFFE;
  UInt32 result = (UInt32)(operand1 + operand2);
  UInt32 hf;
  var timer = new Stopwatch();
  
  timer.Start();
  for (var i = 0; i < 500_000_000; i++)
  {
    hf = (((operand1 ^ result ^ operand2) >> 8) & hfm);
  }
  timer.Stop();
  timer.Elapsed.Dump("(((operand1 ^ result ^ operand2) >> 8) & hfm)");

  timer.Restart();
  for (var i = 0; i < 500_000_000; i++)
  {
    hf = (result >> 8) & hfm;
  }
  timer.Stop();
  timer.Elapsed.Dump("(result >> 8) & hfm");
}
```

The results were pretty consistent.  The 2nd (shorter simpler) code runs ~0.03 seconds slower.

```
(((operand1 ^ result ^ operand2) >> 8) & hfm)
00:00:01.1278598

(result >> 8) & hfm
00:00:01.1612988
```

If I remove the "& hfm" from both, the 2nd code stays about the same timing, but the first code slows down to ~0.002 seconds faster than the 2nd code.  If I then remove the ">> 8" from both, the 1st code finally runs ~0.01 seconds faster than the 2nd code.

According to LINQPad, the IL generated for both code blocks is

`hf = (((operand1 ^ result ^ operand2) >> 8) & hfm);`

```
IL_0022  ldloc.0     // operand1
IL_0023  ldloc.2     // result
IL_0024  xor  
IL_0025  ldloc.1     // operand2
IL_0026  xor  
IL_0027  ldc.i4.8  
IL_0028  shr.un  
IL_0029  ldc.i4.s  10  // 16
IL_002B  and  
IL_002C  stloc.3     // hf
```

`hf = (result >> 8) & hfm;`

```
IL_0073  ldloc.2     // result
IL_0074  ldc.i4.8  
IL_0075  shr.un  
IL_0076  ldc.i4.s  10  // 16
IL_0078  and  
IL_0079  stloc.3     // hf
```

It certainly seems the 2nd code block would be faster...

**UPDATE**
Turns out LINQPad was compiling the code for debug (which makes sense).  When I changed (Edit/Preferences/Query) to "Compile for release ...", both code blocks had very similar timing.

Comment: What mode are you running in?

Comment: Also note that IL does not matter much from performance point of view - you really need to look at JIT'ed machine level assembly to see what is going on (with non-debug JIT). IL generated by C# is not optimized (there are couple relatively small differences between debug and non-debug builds around dead code and objects lifetime. Real optimizations happen at JIT time hance you need to look at JIT'ed code to even guess what may/may not be faster and why.

Comment: Based on my BenchmarkDotNet benchmark attempts I was not able to see consistent results proving that first one is faster, they seem pretty much comparable.

Comment: Based on JIT disasm via [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcDMACR2DCYANgMYBCApgHYkAW6A3uti9iQPZUTDYBGAnsArZaAMyjYAvNgAMvGQqQB9BQoDczbJpYBVAJJVgSAGzZ2ABwoAnMFQAmSKbIAeCDWlbZ9hk2cs37BCcZZwAxcIBRd09zKwBLADcwIS8DYEwgqwoIAFciYHdtXBxCUkoaWgAKAEoipg9PVizc/KdK73SEasqLa1sHbABqPz7A6ujWAF90GYaWLFTDDOwAZQoOexqpAD5sSua8nm3dgA5q7AAyEXEJllnPBY7l0Lirbi3JXcrv3oCBgD1sAdWoDfv0uthjtgzpdrlBxuhJkA===) the second one should be faster but since `operand1 ^ result ^ operand2` != `result` - your are calculating different values and maybe for some reason it is faster to calculate this data.

Comment: [@sharplab v2](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcDMACR2DCYANgMYBCApgHYkAWqaA3utq9iQPZUTDYBGAT2AVstAGZRsAXmwAGPrMVIA+osUBuFti2sAqgEkqwJADZsHAA4UATmCoATJNLkAPBJrRtsBo6fNXbBwRnWRcAMQiAUQ8vC2sASwA3MGFvQ2BMYOsKCABXImAPHVwcQlJKGnoACgBKYuZPLzZsvILnKp8MhBqqyxs7R2wAan9+oJqYtgBfdGKsNKNM7ABlCk4HWvrir06l8RDJpuwxDmsq+KNseKlZdSvsAB5sJFlVDSuhobrGo9Exdpa+V4AD5gdgABw1bAAMj+UEOTTgAHY/giZmg5jhdsEwvFrDxNj9sA1fgsun8Dts2CdrNhzpd4gd7k8Xm9bh8vlSjvsZFU+X1AoMAHrYQFtEUCgbdbCgiFQ2HiKATLm4FHiNHoKZAA===)

Comment: @GuruStron I'm not sure what you mean by what "mode" I'm running in.

Comment: @Lee I mean debug or release.

Comment: @GuruStron That seems to be what the problem was.  In LINQPad I just went to Edit/Preferences/Query and changed "Compile in debug mode" to "Compile in release mode ..." and now they both have very similar timing.  I can't choose your comment as the accepted answer though. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use appropriate tools and techniques for benchmarking. First of all run your benchmark code in Release mode.

Also consider using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) - one of the leading tools for (micro)benchmarking .NET code which has a lot of useful features and also prevents at least some common mistakes (for example it alerts about using Debug mode and/or running with attached debugger).

Based on my experiments the two methods have show similar runtime:

```cs
public class CalcBench
{
    const byte hfm = 0b0001_0000;
  
    UInt16 operand1 = 0x2;
    UInt16 operand2 = 0xFFFE;
    private UInt32 result;

    public CalcBench()
    {
        result = (UInt32)(operand1 + operand2);
    }
        
    [Benchmark]
    public UInt32 First()
    {
        UInt32 hf = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++)
            hf = (((operand1 ^ result ^ operand2) >> 8) & hfm);
        return hf;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public UInt32 Second()
    {
        UInt32 hf = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < 10_000; i++)
         hf = (result >> 8) & hfm;
        return hf;
    }
}
```

On my machine:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2.376 us | 0.0129 us | 0.0121 us |
| Second | 2.365 us | 0.0083 us | 0.0074 us |

Note that for such close microbenchmarking results despite all the library attempts to mitigate that there are a lot of things which can interfere with the results (for example I'm running on notebook which can throttle the CPU, also another processes can compete for resources, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

The difference in performance between these two expressions is likely due to the micro-architectural details of the processor executing the code. Modern CPUs have complex pipelines, multiple execution units, and many optimizations that can lead to non-intuitive performance characteristics.

Imagine the CPU as a super-efficient chef in a high-tech kitchen, juggling a variety of tasks at lightning speed. The two recipes you've given to our chef (the two expressions) have different sets of ingredients and cooking steps.

The first recipe `(((operand1 ^ result ^ operand2) >> 8) & hfm)` has more ingredients and steps, but our star chef is a pro at multitasking. They can chop onions, toss a salad, and flip a pancake all at the same time! This is just like the CPU's ability to interleave multiple instructions and execute them in parallel. So even though the first recipe seems more complex, our skilled chef can whip it up without breaking a sweat!

The second recipe `(result >> 8) & hfm`, on the other hand, has fewer ingredients and steps, but the order in which they need to be done slows down our master chef. It's like trying to juggle while hopping on one leg - not impossible, but it might take a bit more time to get it right!

The takeaway is that you can't always judge a recipe (or an expression) by its apparent complexity. Just like our chef, the CPU is a master of juggling tasks, and sometimes a more complex-looking expression might end up being faster due to the magic of instruction-level parallelism.

Remember, though, the difference in execution time is tiny, like the amount of salt you'd add to a 10-gallon pot of soup. It's there, but it might not make a huge difference in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Style suggestion to nice answer: I would not use salt as "something tiny that has not much impact on 10-galons of soup" :) Water/potatoes/meat or most other components can safely have large variation that would not impact outcome, salt on other hand can **** up food with relatively small increments.

Comment: What if the runtime just partially folds the constants and the difference is actually the result of different values used for calculations?

Comment: @GuruStron All I know is the IL generated for the "& hfm" (the constant) is the same for both code blocks.  I am completely uneducated on how the IL may be or is JIT compiled to native on my AMD Ryzen 7 2700X processor.

Comment: Or maybe just the measurement approach is faulty. For example.